# problems with writing function in db 2

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write a function  using `modifies sql data`.

Here is my code:

```
create function n1n2n3ToCityName()
    returns table (cityname varchar(40),name1 varchar(40),name2 
    varchar(40),name3 varchar(40))
    modifies sql data
    language sql
    begin
    declare tempCityName varchar(40);
    end;
```

When I try to compile this an error occurs:

> [42613][-628] Multiple or conflicting keywords involving the "MODIFIES SQL DATA" clause are present.. SQLCODE=-628, SQLSTATE=42613, DRIVER=4.26.14

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Table functions that modify SQL data can only be inlined, as [stated in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=statements-create-function-sql-scalar-table-row) (see note 4). [Inlined functions](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=statements-compound-sql-inlined) are characterised by `BEGIN ATOMIC`.

Replace `begin` with `begin atomic`.